# Java ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, массивы

Здравствуйте, я только начал изучать язык программирования Java и попытался написать программу сортировки массива чисел, однако вылезла вот такая ошибка `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Вот сама программа:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
    int[]arr = {5,7,2,8,1,0};
    for (int i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
        int min = arr[i];
        int mini = i;
           for(int i2=i;i<=arr.length;i2++){
              if (arr[i2]<min){
                  min=arr[i2];
                  mini=i2;
              }
           }
        arr[mini] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = min;

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) );
  }
}
```

Компилятор указывает что ошибка находится в `if (arr[i2]<min)`

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Сортировка массива идет от меньшего числа к наибольшему.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362640/java-selection-sort-algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Наглядный пример:* у вас 6 элементов в `int[]arr = {5,7,2,8,1,0};`, нумерация элементов идет с 0-го, то есть последний элемент будет под индексом 5.

`arr.length` вернет **длину массива**, а она равна 6-ти. В циклах `for` при проходе на последнем шаге вы пытаетесь обратиться в элементу под индексом 6 (`arr[arr.length]` - 6-й элемент), а его нет. Поэтому ставьте строго **<** в цикле при проверке условия:

```
    int[]arr = {5,7,2,8,1,0};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){ // ВОТ ТУТ
        int min = arr[i];
        int mini = i;
           for (int i2 = i; i2 < arr.length;i2++){ // И ВОТ ТУТ + смените i на i2
              if (arr[i2]<min){
                  min=arr[i2];
                  mini=i2;
              }
           }
        arr[mini] = arr[i];
        arr[i] = min;

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) );
```

Comment: Сделал как вы сказали, но ошибка осталась.

Comment: @EgorovEgor у ваш ошибка была во втором цикле. Посмотрите: **i2** < arr.length должно быть

Comment: Спасибо большое, все теперь работает

Answer (score 3):

Это называется выход за пределы массива. Первый индекс массива начинается с `0`, последний – `arr.lenght - 1`, т.е. условие в цикле должно быть такое: `for(int i2 = i; i < arr.length; i2++)` или такое `for(int i2 = i; i <= arr.length-1; i2++)`

Для массива `int[]arr = {5,7,2,8,1,0};`: `arr[0] = 5`, `arr[5] = 0`, по вашему циклу, значение `i` дойдет до `6`, что больше максимального индекса, из-за этого и выкидывается исключение

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)
Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.

Comment: Т.к. мы SO на русском, то приводя англ. текст следует его перевести на русский.

Comment: Перевод: (примерно) Это исключение означает, что вы обращаетесь к элементу массива испольуя несуществующий индекс, т.е. либо индекс элемента отрицательный, либо его значение больше, чем элементов массива. Ну, как исправить тут уже посоветовали.