# Почему возникает java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0?

Tags: java, массивы, исключения

При выполнении данного кода:

```
int x = 0, y = 0; 
int Arr1[] = new int[x];    //x - simple

for (i = 2; i < 100; i++) {
    for (j = 2; j < i; j++) {
        if (i % j == 0) {
            flag = false;
            y++;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag) {
        System.out.println(i);
        x++;
        Arr1[x - 1] = i; //В этой строке ошибка
    }
    flag=true;
}
```

возникает ошибка:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Почему она возникает?

Comment: Во-первых, укажите строку на которой возникла ошибка. Во-вторых, прочитайте что означает данная ошибка и укажите длину массива и индекс по которому Вы к нему обращаетесь. Код, не имеющий отношения, к ошибке удалите нещадно.

Comment: Определение можно почитать здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501586/java-arrayindexoutofboundsexception

Comment: Код ошибки
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
Строка ошибки(29) at example.hello.main(hello.java:29)

Comment: Тут не видно какая строка 29-я. Отметьте ее в вопросе (его можно редактировать кнопкой «править» под вопросом). Лишний код уберите.

Comment: if (flag) {
             System.out.println(i);
             x++;
             Arr1[x - 1] = i; //29 строка
             }
         flag=true;

Comment: Строку отметил, лишний код убрал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из документации к [`ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html):

> Выбрасывается чтобы указать, что к массиву обратились по некорректному индексу. Индекс либо отрицательный, либо не меньше размера массива

Т.е. к массиву длины `l` можно обращаться по индексам от 0 до `l-1`.

Ошибка возникает либо при обращении отрицательному элементу массива:

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
arr[-1] = 1; //ошибка, нет элемента -1
```

либо к элементу за верхней границей массива

```
int[] arr = new int[10];
arr[10] = 1; //ошибка, нет элемента 10
```

При этом в сообщении об ошибке указывается некорректный индекс:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: **0**

В данном случае длина массива равна 0:

```
int x = 0, y = 0; 
int Arr1[] = new int[x]; // x = 0 пустой массив
```

Соответственно, обратиться к его элементам нельзя, их нет. Попробуйте задать длину массива.

Comment: после того как будет задана длина будет новая ошибка: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, проблема все в той же отмеченной строке, потому как индексы массива с нуля начинаются

Comment: @keekkenen но это уже совсем другая история :)

Comment: @keekkenen это смотря какую длину задать. Я так полагаю с нулем автор вопроса ошибся и массив должен быть длины n+1, где n — максимальное число, которое будет в нем отслеживаться

Comment: история может и другая, но ноги ее растут из того же места и неважно что там хотел найти автор этим кодом

Comment: @keekkenen суть в том, что если автор задаст длину 101, то ошибка не произойдет.

Comment: хз.. имеем java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 101

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69225/discussion-between-default-locale-and-keekkenen).